# find user membership plan WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I want to find the logged-in user's WooCommerce membership plan and then add CSS.
Something like this code but this code doesn't work.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '1-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3333] {display:none;} option[value=3334] {display:none;}</style>';
} else if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '2-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3332] {display:none;} option[value=3334] {display:none;}</style>';
}
else if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '3-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3332] {display:none;} option[value=3333] {display:none;}</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through a wordpress hook which will echo the css in the correct place on the page. The best hook to use would be the `wp_head` action.

You can wrap your code like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

  if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '1-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3333] {display:none;} option[value=3334] {display:none;}</style>';
  } else if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '2-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3332] {display:none;} option[value=3334] {display:none;}</style>';
  } else if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, '3-level' ) ) {
    echo '<style>option[value=3332] {display:none;} option[value=3333] {display:none;}</style>';
  }
});
```

You should also do a check inside that function to make sure you are on the correct page before outputting the css.